# OpenCV on a cheap board

Tags: opencv

For my senior year project, I require a cheap board, (not more than $100, excluding shipping) that is capable of running OpenCV related, webcam using software that can also have general purpose I/O pins.

For this purpose, I bought Raspberry PI model B, but after installing raspbian OS, I noticed that the CPU usage is %100 even sometimes when I am only moving the mouse. Do you think that the Raspberry PI is capable of executing such OpenCV code? The code recognizes round shape objects with specific color in the point of view. As I have said, I also need to use several General Purpose I/O pins to interface three sensors, but I think it wont be a problem. Do I have to perform some optimization on RPi for my code to run fluently? For my purpose I dont need monitor, keyboard, wifi or mouse.

Another question, if you think that RPi is not suitable for my application can you recommend any boards within the specs?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you interfacing to the webcam? Usb, network, some lower level camera interface?

Comment: For Raspberry PI, USB. But I can also use any other as long as it is not really hard to interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the raspberry's CPU is running so much might be because you have a graphical interface. Get ride of that (by reinstalling raspbian without it), and it should be much faster. ;)